# GLSL Instancing - Passing ModelMatrix

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have done many searches on Google/Stackflow and can't find an answer to my specific issue. I tried to implement instancing using a patched sphere mesh and the following references:

http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html

https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing

I have tried to debug my own code but nothing seems to be working... I am consistently getting an output that looks like the modelmatrix values are corrupt or setup incorrectly. Here is what it looks like at different camera rotations when passing in an Identity matrix for the Model:

[Instance Model Matrix #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BOnY.png)

[Instance Model Matrix #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua9mO.png)

If I hard-code the model matrix in the vertex shader to be the Identity Matrix then it comes out just fine:

[Hard-code Model Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eurta.png)

So it seems to me that the model matrix is not being passed in correctly and since I've spend days reviewing my code and trying different things. I'm hoping someone can review this and spot the problem.. THANKS!

### InstanceObject::Init()

```
for (unsigned int Level = 0; Level < Levels; Level++)
{
    FrameTicks[Level] = 0;
    VBO_SeedVector[Level] = 0;
    VBO_ModelMatrix[Level] = 0;

    //. Bind VAO for Object's Level of Detail
    glBindVertexArray(Meshes->GetMesh(Level)->GetVAO());

    //. Generate Buffers for Object's SeedVector
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_SeedVector[Level]);

    //. Generate Instance Array for Object's SeedVector
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector4f), (void*)0);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);

    //. Generate Buffers for Object's ModelMatrix
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);

    //. Generate Instance Array for Object's ModelMatrix
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(0 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(1 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(2 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
    glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(3 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

    ObjectSeeds.push_back(std::vector<Vector4f>());
    ObjectModels.push_back(std::vector<Matrix4f>());
}
```

### InstanceObject::Update()

```
//. Load Instance Arrays into VAOs
for (unsigned int Level = 0; Level < Levels; Level++)
{
    glBindVertexArray(Meshes->GetMesh(Level)->GetVAO());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_SeedVector[Level]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ObjectSeeds[Level].size() * sizeof(Vector4f), &ObjectSeeds[Level], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ObjectModels[Level].size() * sizeof(Matrix4f), &ObjectModels[Level], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

### InstanceObject::Render()

```
//. Empty Detailed Mesh
if (Meshes == nullptr)
    return;

//. Enable VAA for Px, Py, Pz, U
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0);

//. Enable VAA for Nx, Ny, Nz, V
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 0);

//. Enable VAA for Seed Vector
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 0);

//. Enable VAA for Model Matrix
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

//. Render Instances For Each Ring
for (unsigned int Level = Levels - 1; Level > 0; Level--)
{
    unsigned int RingSize = ObjectModels[Level].size();

    //. Empty Ring
    if (RingSize == 0)
        continue;

    BaseMesh* Mesh = Meshes->GetMesh(Level);

    //. Empty Mesh
    if (Mesh == nullptr)
        continue;

    unsigned int VAO = Mesh->GetVAO();

    if (VAO == 0)
        continue;

    //. Render Instances
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, Mesh->Elements.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, RingSize);
}

glDisableVertexAttribArray(6);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

### Vertex Shader

```
#version 440

layout (location = 0) in vec4 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 Normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 Seed;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 ModelCol0;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 ModelCol1;
layout (location = 5) in vec4 ModelCol2;
layout (location = 6) in vec4 ModelCol3;

//uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

out vec3 mPosition;
out vec3 vPosition;
out vec3 vNormal;
out vec2 vSample;

void main()
{
    mPosition = Position.xyz;

    mat4 vModel = mat4(1.0);

    vModel[0] = ModelCol0;
    vModel[1] = ModelCol1;
    vModel[2] = ModelCol2;
    vModel[3] = ModelCol3;

    vPosition = (vModel * vec4(mPosition.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vNormal = (vModel * vec4(Normal.xyz, 0.0)).xyz;
    vSample = vec2(Position.w, Normal.w);

    gl_Position = Projection * View * vModel * vec4(mPosition.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

---

### 04/09/18 UPDATE:

I updated the InstanceObject::Init() to bind the VBO before the VAA calls as follows:

```
for (unsigned int Level = 0; Level < Levels; Level++)
{
    FrameTicks[Level] = 0;
    VBO_SeedVector[Level] = 0;
    VBO_ModelMatrix[Level] = 0;

    //. Bind VAO for Object's Level of Detail
    glBindVertexArray(Meshes->GetMesh(Level)->GetVAO());

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glGenBuffers"))
        return false;

    //. Generate Buffers for Object's SeedVector
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_SeedVector[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glGenBuffers"))
        return false;

    //. Enable Vertex Attribute Arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glEnableVertexAttribArray"))
        return false;

    //. Bind Buffer to Setup Instance Array
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_SeedVector[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindBuffer"))
        return false;

    //. Generate Instance Array for Object's SeedVector
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector4f), (void*)0);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glVertexAttribPointer"))
        return false;

    //. Apply Attribute Divisors
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glVertexAttribDivisor"))
        return false;

    //. Unbind Buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //.
    //.
    //.

    //. Generate Buffers for Object's ModelMatrix
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glGenBuffers"))
        return false;

    //. Enable Vertex Attribute Arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glEnableVertexAttribArray"))
        return false;

    //. Bind Buffer to Setup Instance Arrays
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindBuffer"))
        return false;

    //. Generate Instance Array for Object's ModelMatrix
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(0 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(1 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(2 * sizeof(Vector4f)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Matrix4f), (void*)(3 * sizeof(Vector4f)));

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glVertexAttribPointer"))
        return false;

    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glVertexAttribDivisor"))
        return false;

    //. Unbind Buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //. Bind Default VAO ~ move to outside For Loop
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindVertexArray"))
        return false;

    ObjectSeeds.push_back(std::vector<Vector4f>());
    ObjectModels.push_back(std::vector<Matrix4f>());
}
```

That all works without throwing any GL errors but I do get an GL_INVALID_OPERATION in the InstanceObject::Update() section when I try to bind the VAO to load the update data:

```
    //. Load Instance Arrays into VAOs
for (unsigned int Level = 0; Level < Levels; Level++)
{
    glBindVertexArray(Meshes->GetMesh(Level)->GetVAO()); //. GL_INVALID OPERATION

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindVertexArray"))
        return;

    //glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_SeedVector[Level]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_SeedVector[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindBuffer"))
        return;

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ObjectSeeds[Level].size() * sizeof(Vector4f), &ObjectSeeds[Level], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBufferData"))
        return;

    //glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ModelMatrix[Level]);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBindBuffer"))
        return;

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ObjectModels[Level].size() * sizeof(Matrix4f), &ObjectModels[Level], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (!LogErrorGL(std::cout, "glBufferData"))
        return;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `InstanceObject::Init()`, you never actually *bind* any of the VBOs you are creating.

The GL'a attribute array pointer contains  always a reference to the buffer object name, and the byte offset into this buffer (among other things like data formats, and stride, and so on). `glVertexAttribPointer` will store the name of the *currently bound* `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` in the attribute pointer.

Comment: I added the glBindBuffer() command after the glGenBuffers() command before the glEnableVertexAttribArray() parts and it still does not work. Any other thoughts?